# No windows 10 boot loading in grub with ubuntu 16.04 and windows 10

Tags: boot, 16.04, windows-10

I had preinstalled ubuntu 16.04. I installed windows 10. Windows was working but I wasn't able to see grub. So I used live ubuntu USB to update grub. After that I was able to see grub with ubuntu and windows both. Here, ubuntu boots successfully but when I choose windows 10, it didn't start. Is there anything that can help me?

Comment: Please run [Boot-Repair](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log.